# Javascript SlideFadeToggle Form on Page Load

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I apologize in advance if this is a rookie question. I am just learning to program/create a website and I can't find the solution to my problem.

I have a form on my website that appears/disappears after clicking on a button. I want the form to be hidden upon the page loading. As of now, the form is visible on the page once it loads, then when someone clicks the button the form hides/unhides. My current code is shown below. Could someone please help? Thanks!

```
<script>

function deselect(e) {
  $('.pop').slideFadeToggle(function() {
    e.removeClass('selected');
  });    
}

$(function() {
  $('#contact').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      deselect($(this));               
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $('.pop').slideFadeToggle();
    }
    return false;
  });

 $('.close').on('click', function() {
    deselect($('#contact'));
    return false;
  });

});

$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
  return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, 'slow', easing, callback);
};

</script>
```

Comment: in deselect function, where are you sending easing? you are passing the call back directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the custom function to accept a timing parameter as follows:

```
$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, timing, callback) {
  return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, timing , easing, callback);
};
```

and call it in `ready()` handler with `0` timing to hide the form on page load.

```js
function deselect(e) {
  $('.pop').slideFadeToggle(function() {
    e.removeClass('selected');
  });    
}

$(function() {
  $('.pop').slideFadeToggle("linear",0)
  $('#contact').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      deselect($(this));               
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $('.pop').slideFadeToggle();
    }
    return false;
  });

 $('.close').on('click', function() {
    deselect($('#contact'));
    return false;
  });

});

$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, timing, callback) {
  return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, timing , easing, callback);
};
```

```css
form{
  background:dodgerblue;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="pop">
  <input type="text" /><br/>
  <input type="text" /><br/>
</form>
<input type="button" id="contact" value="toggle"/>
```